# ruby re-order array of dates with string parts retaining empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, date

I have this array of dates that includes empty strings and I want to reorder it in two ways and each case the empty string should be in front of the array always.

```
[" ", "2018-10-01", "2019", " ",  "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10", "2019-01-01", "2017", "2018-05", "2018", "2018-05-10",  " "]
```

The first outcome is to re-order this way

```
["", "", "", "2019-10-01", "2019-10", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019", "2018-01-01", "2018-05", "2018-05-10", "2017"]
```

The second way I want to be able to re-order it this way:

```
[" ", " ", " ", "2017", "2018-01-01", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10-01", "2019-10", "2019"]
```

I tried the code below but i didn't get the desire result.

```
  ["", "", "", "2019-10-01", "2019-10", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019", "2018-01-01", "2018-05", "2018-05-10", "2017"].sort_by { |date| parts = date.split('-').map(&:to_i) }
```

*update*

will it be possible for the sort ascending to come out in this order. yy-mm-dd, then yy-mm, then just year which means sort ascending should be in this form 
`[" ", " ", " ", "2017","2018-05-10",  "2018-05", "2018-10-01",  "2018", "2019-01-01", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10", "2019"]`. So it is not a regular sort ascending but it is based on pattern that results in the order above.

Thesame pattern applies to sort descending.

Comment: your starting array doesn't match the data of your expected outcomes, please fix it

Comment: You can filter the array so empty strings go to one array and dates to another. Then sort the dates array and join the two arrays again.

Comment: I the answer I provided below makes sense but because your output examples don't match your input data, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What @lacostenycoder means is that, for the second ordering, the elements `"2018-05" and "2018-05-10"` have been omitted.

Comment: You're also missing `"2018"` which is omitted from both results. "reordering" shouldn't remove any elements. Based upon what requirements are the results missing some elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution #1 - normal sorting

You could first partition the list based upon the fact that the string is blank or not. Then sort all the present dates and concatenate them back together.

```
dates = [" ", "2018-10-01", "2019", " ",  "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10", "2019-01-01", "2017", "2018-05", "2018", "2018-05-10",  " "]

asc = ->(a, b) { a <=> b }
desc = ->(a, b) { b <=> a }

blank, present = dates.partition(&:blank?)
result1 = blank + present.sort(&desc)
#=> [" ", " ", " ", "2019-10", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-01-01", "2019", "2018-10-01", "2018-05-10", "2018-05", "2018", "2017"]
result2 = blank + present.sort(&asc)
#=> [" ", " ", " ", "2017", "2018", "2018-05", "2018-05-10", "2018-10-01", "2019", "2019-01-01", "2019-06", "2019-06-20", "2019-10"]
```

**Note:** That this simply sorts the array based upon alphabetical order. Which is fine as long as you're using the `yyyy-mm-dd` format (with proceding zeros if only one digit). If dates are supplied in another format you want to convert them to a date first.

## Solution #2 - assume highest value for missing month or day

```
strings = [" ", "2018-10-01", "2019", " ",  "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10", "2019-01-01", "2017", "2018-05", "2018", "2018-05-10",  " "]

array_to_date = lambda do |(year, month, day)|
  month ||= 12
  day ||= 31

  begin
    Date.new(year, month, day)
  rescue ArgumentError
    raise unless (1..12).cover? month
    raise unless (1..31).cover? day
    array_to_date.call([year, month, day - 1])
  end
end

date_regex = /\A(\d{4})(?:-(\d{2})(?:-(\d{2}))?)?\z/
yyyy_mm_dd = ->(date_string) { date_regex.match(date_string).captures.compact.map(&:to_i) }
string_to_date = yyyy_mm_dd >> array_to_date

asc = ->(a, b) { string_to_date.call(a) <=> string_to_date.call(b) }
desc = ->(a, b) { string_to_date.call(b) <=> string_to_date.call(a) }

dates, non_dates = strings.partition(&date_regex.method(:match?))
result1 = non_dates + dates.sort(&desc)
#=> [" ", " ", " ", "2019", "2019-10", "2019-06", "2019-06-20", "2019-01-01", "2018", "2018-10-01", "2018-05", "2018-05-10", "2017"]
result2 = non_dates + dates.sort(&asc)
#=> [" ", " ", " ", "2017", "2018-05-10", "2018-05", "2018-10-01", "2018", "2019-01-01", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10", "2019"]
```

**Note:** This is not the most effective solution, since the strings have to be converted every time the `#sort` block is called. If you're working with large arrays you can convert all the values first and save them in a hash. Then look them up when sorting.

The current regex also allows strings like `"0000-00-00"` to pass you might want to make it more specific.

Comment: will it be possible for the sort ascending to come out in this order. yy-mm-dd, then yy-mm, then just year which means sort ascending should be in this form 
`[" ", " ", " ", "2017","2018-05-10",  "2018-05", "2018-10-01",  "2018", "2019-01-01", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10", "2019"]`. So it is not a regular sort ascending but it is based on pattern that results in the order above.

Comment: @brg I've added a second solution to the answer that does what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [" ", "2018-10-01", "2019", " ",  "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-10",
       "2019-01-01", "2017", "2018-05", "2018", "2018-05-10",  " "]
```

The ascending sort:

```
def sort_asc(arr)
  arr.sort
end
```

```
sort_asc(arr)
  #=> [" ", " ", " ",
  #    "2017",
  #    "2018", "2018-05", "2018-05-10", "2018-10-01",
  #    "2019", "2019-01-01", "2019-06", "2019-06-20", "2019-10"]
```

The descending sort:

```
def sort_dsc(arr)
  arr.sort_by { |s| s == ' ' ? '99' : s }.reverse
end
```

```
sort_dsc(arr)
  #=> [" ", " ", " ",
  #    "2019-10", "2019-06-20", "2019-06", "2019-01-01", "2019",
  #    "2018-10-01", "2018-05-10", "2018-05", "2018",
  #    "2017"]
```